# Check if a second list contains all values of the first

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following problem:

I have a Database with a table where I save a String and a Date.
In this table I add an Entry if a certain assignment is printed and when.
On the other hand I have a Database Table from where I get the assignments to do for today.
After inserting the new entry into the Database I select the String with the assignment number and put it into a database,
so I can compare those two lists and check if the list with the printed elements contains all values from the assignments to print today.
How can I achieve this?
I've tried several methods but it always returns false.

The methods I've tried:

```
if (serial_list_printed.All(x => serial_list.Contains(x)) == true)
{
    status = true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

2nd Method:

```
if (serial_list.All(x => serial_list_printed.All(y => y == x)))
{
    status = true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

How can I check that all the List of Strings with the printed assignment numbers, contains the list of today's assignments?

Comment: You can use Except linq method. If u can provide, post the classes involved in the collection

Comment: Change your write for debugging : Console.WriteLine("False," + x);

Comment: [Enjoy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1) to get difference between two list and count length of result,

```
var status = serial_list.Except(serial_list_printed).Any();

if(!status)
   Console.WriteLine("False");
```